# Solana SMS 500 Error: Unable to resolve module with Metaplex SDK and Project Serum Anchor

Tags: anchor, metaplex-js, mobile

> Error: Unable to resolve module crypto from
> SolanaMobileDAppScaffold\node_modules@bundlr-network\client\build\common\transaction.js:
> crypto could not be found within the project or in these directories:
> node_modules@bundlr-network\client\node_modules

Metaplex-sdk/js and Project-serum/anchor both experience issues with the following packages in React Native:

- Crypto
- Assert
- StringDecoder
- Stream

These node libraries require polyfill and are not compatible with React Native.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by https://github.com/BoxInThePARK/mobile-nft-mint-example is as follows:

In package.json, add:

```
node-libs-react-native": "^1.2.1"
```

In metro.config.js

```
resolver: {
     extraNodeModules: require('node-libs-react-native')
},
```

Make sure your server is stopped. Delete your node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall.

Shoutout to [Mike Sulistio](https://twitter.com/MikeSulistio) for the resources